# Copy CString to TCHAR* using a _tcscpy_s

Tags: c++, c-strings

I'm trying to copy a CString value to TCHAR* array using a following code:

```
CString m_str = L"ABCDE FGHIJ LMNOPQ";


TCHAR *lpszText = new TCHAR[m_str.GetLength() + 1];
memset(lpszText, 0, (m_str.GetLength() + 1) * sizeof(TCHAR));
_tcscpy_s(lpszText, _tcslen(m_str), m_str.GetString());
```

But I get an error:
Debug Assertion Failed! Expression: (L"Buffer is too small" && 0)

Any help please?

Comment: Should it be at least _tcslen(m_str ) + sizeof( L'\0' ) ?

Comment: Thank you @VladfromMoscow, now it is working ok

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That line is logically incorrect:

```
_tcscpy_s(lpszText, _tcslen(m_str), m_str.GetString());
```

Second parameter of `_tcscpy_s` should give count of `TCHAR` in destination buffer (`lpszText`).
The `_tcslen(m_str)` is giving one less than that (it is [documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/strlen-wcslen-mbslen-mbslen-l-mbstrlen-mbstrlen-l?view=vs-2019) to exclude terminating null) and so the call fails. You
should call it with what you allocated for `lpszText`:

```
_tcscpy_s(lpszText, m_str.GetLength() + 1, m_str.GetString());
```